# Alembic и MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, alembic

Имеется БД, в ней таблицы с данными.
Первую миграцию `Alembic` произвел без проблем. Однако, когда я изменила тип поля (был `String(100)`, стал `String(300)`), `Alembic` не определил это изменение.
Я поискала в документации и там написано, что он может определять типы и нужно внести просто сроку `compare_type = True` в `online` и `offline` функции. Я внесла:

```py
def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
     ...
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        compare_type = True
    )

def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    ....
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, 
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            compare_type = True
        )
```

Запустила миграцию и ничего... файл пустой.

```py
revision = '6c7efd759f39'
down_revision = 'e47d44dc7f2e'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    pass


def downgrade() -> None:
    pass
```

Может быть я плохо умею читать и не туда вставила строку?
Но он не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему